# Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Whenever I run 'react-native run-android' I get this error message at 99%:

Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>   Failed to transform artifact 'imagepipeline-base.aar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-java-res}.
>   Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\ronsi.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\36b5e92c216129ce5187eea1bb53cf04.
>   Cannot parse result path string:
>   Failed to transform artifact 'soloader.aar (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.6.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-java-res}.
>   Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\ronsi.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6e75901105f09a338e73b93bf40fcae8.
>   Cannot parse result path string:

BUILD FAILED in 11s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:623:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:641:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\ronsi\Documents\repos\bahad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\ronsi\Documents\repos\bahad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at C:\Users\ronsi\Documents\repos\bahad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\ronsi\Documents\repos\bahad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by deleting folder:
C:\Users\UserName.gradle\caches\transforms-2

Answer (score 1):

Go to your android folder run Command:

```
gradlew clean
```

and then run:

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: Yep it printed: BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed

Answer (score 0):

Just write

`cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`

Then write

`react-native run-android`